# slow query fetch time

Tags: google-cloud-sql, database-performance, mysql-8.0

I am using gcp cloud sql (mysql 8.0.18) and I am trying to execute a query for only 5000 rows,

```
SELECT  * FROM client_1079.c_crmleads ORDER BY LeadID DESC LIMIT 5000;
```

but I think the execution is taking long time to fetch data

here is the time details

> Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 5,000  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.797 sec. (+ 117.609 sec. network)

Instance configuration is vCPU: 8 , RAM: 20 GB, SSD: 410GB

screenshot of gcp cloud sql instance

[image]

also I am facing some issues on high table_open_cache and high ram utilization.

[image: table_open_cache]

how do I reduce open_table_cache also how to increase instance performance?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the size of the data retrieved is quite large and the time spent on sending the data from the SQL instance to your App is the reason of the latency observed.

You may review your use case and maybe retrieve less information, or try to parallellize queries, or improve the SQL instance I/O performance (it is related to [DB Disk Size](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance)).